# How to do an user interface in python

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib

I need to do an user interface where I can change the possition of the point with the arrows coming out of it and change the value of the arrows too. For example: the point is in the xyz(0,0,0) and now I want it on xyz(0,1,1) and the same for the arrows.

I have done this...

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, combinations
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect("equal")

#draw cube
r = [-1, 1]
for s, e in combinations(np.array(list(product(r,r,r))), 2):
    if np.sum(np.abs(s-e)) == r[1]-r[0]:
        ax.plot3D(*zip(s,e), color="b")

#draw a point
ax.scatter([0],[0],[0],color="g",s=100)

#draw a vector
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d

class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs, *args, **kwargs):
        FancyArrowPatch.__init__(self, (0,0), (0,0), *args, **kwargs)
        self._verts3d = xs, ys, zs

    def draw(self, renderer):
        xs3d, ys3d, zs3d = self._verts3d
        xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, renderer.M)
        self.set_positions((xs[0],ys[0]),(xs[1],ys[1]))
        FancyArrowPatch.draw(self, renderer)

a = Arrow3D([0,1],[0,1],[0,1], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="k")
b = Arrow3D([0,1],[0,0],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="r")
c = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,0],[0,1], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="b")
d = Arrow3D([0,1],[0,1],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="g")
e = Arrow3D([0,1],[0,0],[0,1], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="c")
f = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,-0.5],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="m")

ax.add_artist(a)
ax.add_artist(b)
ax.add_artist(c)
ax.add_artist(d)
ax.add_artist(e)
ax.add_artist(f)
plt.show()
```

But now I need to do an user interface for me to be able to change the possition of the dot and the value of each arrow.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specifically are you stuck on? We generally help with specific issue, rather that 'write this for me'-type of questions. Try showing us a specific snippet of code that draws the cube, and then what you're doing that you'd expect to draw the 6 vectors

Comment: So what's the question? How to draw the cube and the arrows, or how to do the user interface to (manually?) change the position of the objects? [Beware of the xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: yeah! Now i need to do the user interface to change the position of the objects! :S I don't know how to do it!

Comment: Maybe consider editing both the title and the first paragraph. Afterall you seem to have solved all that you ask for there.